# How to resolve php conflict

Tags: php, centos7

I attempted to upgrade from php 5.4 to 5.6 on a DigitalOcean Centos7. 
Now it seems I have an orphan from the old php somewhere.
I'm trying to get php-fann running, but it won't install because of this conflict.
Clearly I didn't upgrade php properly, but now I don't know how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Ran this

```
yum install php-pecl-fann
```

Got this

```
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
```

Ran this

```
rpm -ql php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
```

Got this

```
package php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 is not installed
```

Ran this

```
yum info php
```

Got this

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.scalabledns.com
* elrepo: elrepo.org 
* epel: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
* extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
* ius: mirrors.kernel.org
* updates: mirror.tocici.com
* webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
 Available Packages
Name        : php
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.4.16
Release     : 42.el7
Size        : 1.4 M
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
```

Ran this

```
php -v
```

And got this

```
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2017 22:31:39)
```

Ran this

```
yum list installed | grep -i php
```

Got this

```
php56w.x86_64                           5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-cli.x86_64                       5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-common.x86_64                    5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-gd.x86_64                        5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-mbstring.x86_64                  5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-mcrypt.x86_64                    5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-mysqlnd.x86_64                   5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-odbc.x86_64                      5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-opcache.x86_64                   5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-pdo.x86_64                       5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-pgsql.x86_64                     5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-soap.x86_64                      5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
php56w-xml.x86_64                       5.6.30-1.w7                    @webtatic
```

So yum info seems to be the only thing that thinks php5.4 in installed.

Comment: You're using the webtatic repo and are have installed php56w-common from it. pecl-fann requires php-common which is different than php56w-common. Do you specifically need the builds from webtatic?

Comment: @castis I don't have a specific need for webtatic. It was used in a post I found on upgrading php and it looked the most consistent with my environment.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!

`mv /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.old`

`yum install php-pecl-fann`

`mv /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.old /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i having same error when install php-xml, however, the original answer does not work as no such repo exists.
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-xml

actually the error message is kind of misleading, for me, I just choose difference php-xml version.  in my case:

## before install:

```
        # yum list installed|grep php |grep webtatic
        php56w.x86_64                  5.6.31-2.w7             @webtatic
        php56w-cli.x86_64              5.6.31-2.w7             @webtatic
        php56w-common.x86_64           5.6.31-2.w7             @webtatic
        php56w-mysqlnd.x86_64          5.6.31-2.w7             @webtatic
        php56w-opcache.x86_64          5.6.31-2.w7             @webtatic
        php56w-pdo.x86_64              5.6.31-2.w7             @webtatic`    


#command
         yum install php56w-xml.x86_64
#after install
`    php56w.x86_64                  5.6.33-1.w7             @webtatic
    php56w-cli.x86_64              5.6.33-1.w7             @webtatic
    php56w-common.x86_64           5.6.33-1.w7             @webtatic
    php56w-mysqlnd.x86_64          5.6.33-1.w7             @webtatic
    php56w-opcache.x86_64          5.6.33-1.w7             @webtatic
    php56w-pdo.x86_64              5.6.33-1.w7             @webtatic
    php56w-xml.x86_64              5.6.33-1.w7             @webtatic
`
```